# How save bidimensional list to image in python?

Tags: image, python-3.x

I have a big bidimensional list of integer value. Each value represent a pixel and needs to match a color but obviously similar value needs to have similar color. Here an example of my list:

```
list=[[0,10,3,9,23,0], [7,0,0,0,0,10], [12,1,2,7,11,12], [0,0,0,34,1,9]]
```

"list" is a rectangle of 4 rows and each row have 6 columns. 0 value needs to match to no color, in other word 0 value is trasparent color. I try to use PIL but I didn't obtain the right result. Here the test code:

```
from PIL import Image

list=[[0,10,3,9,23,0], [7,0,0,0,0,10], [12,1,2,7,11,12], [0,0,0,34,1,9]]
new=Image.new("P", (4,6))
new.putdata(list)
new.save('test.tif')
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause for the failure is during `new.putdata(list)`, which expects a sequence object (I guess a 2D array doesn't count as a sequence object).

The fix is to convert your 2D array into a 1D array.  One example of how to do this is:

```
sequence = [list[x][y] for x in range(len(list)) for y in range(len(list[0]))]
```

So the following code should work properly:

```
from PIL import Image

list=[[0,10,3,9,23,0], [7,0,0,0,0,10], [12,1,2,7,11,12], [0,0,0,34,1,9]]
new=Image.new("P", (6,4))
sequence = [list[x][y] for x in range(len(list)) for y in range(len(list[0]))]
new.putdata(sequence)
new.save('test.tif')
```

Comment: Something wrong with your code. If you see the result the 'test.tif' is a rectangle 4 column sand 6 rows. The right result should be a rectangle 6 columns and 4 rows.

Comment: new=Image.new("P", (6,4)) is correct. Anyway there is another problem and it's the coluor. With this approch you have grey scale color (black to white). How is possible obtain other color? I don't know something like: low value blue color, after green, after yellow and red for high value (like gradient)